# PowerBi Dax: sum only first row in duplicates

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following table

| Location | Domain | Phase | Answer | Domain score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loc1 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| loc1 | A | 2 | 1 | 0.5 |
| loc1 | A | 2 | 0 | 0.5 |
| loc1 | A | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| loc1 | A | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| loc2 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| loc2 | A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| loc2 | A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| loc2 | A | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| loc2 | A | 4 | 0 | 0 |

Now I want to sum the domain score per Location and domain but for duplicate phases I only want to sum the first row. so for phase 2 i only want to add a single Domain score. Which would result in:

| Location | Domain | Phase | Answer | Domain score | End score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| loc1 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1.5 |
| loc1 | A | 2 | 1 | 0.5 | 1.5 |
| loc1 | A | 2 | 0 | 0.5 | 1.5 |
| loc1 | A | 3 | 0 | 0 | 1.5 |
| loc1 | A | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1.5 |
| loc2 | A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| loc2 | A | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| loc2 | A | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| loc2 | A | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| loc2 | A | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Is this possible in DAX? I allready tried to generate a kind of rownumber partion by() construction but I cannot get it working...

Comment: sum only first row in duplicates : what is the rule to get the 1st row ?

Answer (score 1):

I will use "Data" as a name for your table. Create a measure (not a calculated column):

```
End Score =
CALCULATE (
    SUMX (
        SUMMARIZE (
            Data,
            Data[Location],
            Data[Domain],
            Data[Phase],
            Data[Domain score]
        ),
        Data[Domain score]
    ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Data, Data[Domain], Data[Location] )
)
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

- SUMMARIZE function takes all your columns except "Answer", and creates a virtual table where every row is unique, thus suppressing duplicates;
- SUMX iterates over this new table, and sums up domain scores;
- ALLEXCEPT then makes sure that results are not filtered by any fields except location and domain.

Note though, the better way to solve this problem is to answer why your data has these duplicates in the first place, and if they could be removed from the data model. Using fancy DAX to fix data issues is not a good practice.